# Authentication failure in spring security.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security-oauth2

This is my .jsp page

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="container">
<div id="errorDiv" align="center"><%
                 String sl = request.getParameter("sl");
                 if(sl != null && sl.equalsIgnoreCase("f")){%>
                  <b>Invalid Login!</b>
                 <%} %>
    </div>
        <div class="spacer-60px"></div>
        <div class="spacer-60px"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span14">
                <div class="span4"></div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <form name="login" action="/missionbhageeratha/login.html" method="POST" >

                        <div class="boxcontainer" >

                            <div class="widget_login">
                                <div class="login-username" style="height: 20">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" type="text" style="height: 20"
                                        name="username" placeholder="username" autofocus="autofocus" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="login-password">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password"
                                        placeholder="password" />

                                        <a href="javascript:call();" class="btn" id="continueBtn" tabindex='22'>Log In</a>
                                        <a href="/missionbhageeratha/newUserCreation.html" class="btn" id="continueBtn" tabindex='22'>new user registration</a>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">

function call(){
    document.login.username.value = document.login.username.value.toLowerCase();
    submitForm();
}
function enterKey(evt) {
    var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
    if (evt.keyCode == 13 ) {
        call();
    }
}
document.onkeypress = enterKey;
</script>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is spring-security.xml file.Here i am getting authentication failure url.after typing in username and password it is not getting redirected to  the page that i want to, i.e....
 enter code here`

```
<%@page import="com.cgg.util.StringUtils"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<div class="banner">
<div class="spacer-20px;"></div>
                <div class="container clearfix">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                <div class="pageTitle">
<marquee><font >WELCOME Administrator</font></marquee>              </div>
                <br>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
</div>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">


    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <!--    <intercept-url pattern="/*.html" access="hasRole('USER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/*.html" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/*.html" access="hasRole('AUTH')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/*.html" access="permitAll"/> -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <form-login login-page="/signin.html" default-target-url="/signin.html" authentication-failure-url="/signin.html?sl=f" 
                    always-use-default-target="true" login-processing-url="/login.html" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>

        <logout logout-success-url="/signin.html" logout-url="/auth/springSecurityLogoutAction.html" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>

        <anonymous />
    </http>

      <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
         <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="myDataSource" 
            users-by-username-query="select username password, case when active_flg = 'Y' then 'true' else 'false' end enabled from public.user_mst where username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, r.role_desc from public.user_mst u, public.role_mst r where u.username = r.role_desc
            and u.username = ?"     role-prefix="none" />
            <password-encoder hash="md5">
                <salt-source user-property="username"/>
            </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider> 
    </authentication-manager> 


</beans>
```

this my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <display-name>MissionBhageeratha</display-name>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

     <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


<context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-application.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-hibernate.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
             </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>MissionBhageeratha</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>MissionBhageeratha</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
                 <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    <session-config>
                <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way.

security.xml

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="webAccess">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />        
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

    <security:form-login 
        login-processing-url="/login"
        login-page="/loginform" 
        default-target-url="/" 
        authentication-failure-url="/loginform?error=1" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />

    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <security:csrf />

</security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager id="webAccess">


      <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_EDITOR" />
       </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>

  </security:authentication-manager>
```

And in you jsp:

```
        <spring:url value="/login" var="loginURL"/>             
    <form name='loginForm' action="${loginURL}" method='post'>

        <!-- username -->
            <input id="Username" name="username" type="text">
        </div>

        <!-- password -->
        <input id="Password" name="password" type="password">
        </div>

        <!-- CSRF -->               
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />

        <br/>

        <!-- submit -->                     
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-success center-block" />

    </form>
```